# Why is my java spring project running in AWS Cloud9 shutting down after running a while?

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, aws-cloud9

I'm trying out a few things with the free tier of AWS.

I have a 3rd party server running on a Windows instance, a mySQL db running on RDS, and I'm running a spring app from within Cloud9 on a linux instance, which calls both those other servers/instances. I do most of the development locally, but I went with Cloud9 so I could tweak a few things (code, config, log, etc.) as well as run it.

It works fine for the most part, but after running for a couple hours (being started with mvn spring-boot:run) it sometimes just ends. This is usually when I'm not actively logged on and monitoring it - could that be part of it? Is there a timeout somewhere for Cloud9?

I've done a quick look into CloudWatch metrics and didn't see anything jump out. There's no errors in my app logs, either.

I noticed on the instance description that there is a stop - hibernation setting but it is disabled.

Answer (score 2):

When launch an AWS Cloud9 environment, you can nominate to activate a **Cost Saving setting**:

> Choose a predetermined amount of time to auto-hibernate your environment and prevent unnecessary charges. We recommend a hibernation settings of half an hour of no activity to maximize savings.

[image: Cloud9 Cost Saving Settings]

This might explain why your environment stops after a while.

Comment: Thanks! Although it's not easy to find how to change this. I thought it might be under EC2 instances, and another question's answer suggested Cloud9->Preferences, but I couldn't find that, and had to go into my Cloud9 project settings->EC2 Instance->Stop my environment

Answer (score 0):

If you start your application in command line it will be destroyed as you disconnect from it. This explains why everything is ok when you're actively monitoring it. Try [starting processes as services](https://dzone.com/articles/run-your-java-application-as-a-service-on-ubuntu) or using [bash screens](http://aperiodic.net/screen/quick_reference). Although last is much less preferred.